# Is my TDD/algorithm question too broad?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am going to ask a question, but I am not sure if it will been closed shortly afterwards.

Can you give me a hint if Stack Overflow is the right place for this question and how can I make my question less broad?

> I want to check group of algorithms which has up to 8 input options.
>   The naive idea would be to check all possibilities via brute force.
>   How can I reduce it without leaving out required combinations?
>
> Since I do not know it better I'm using multiple loops which ends in
>   worst case in a `O(n8)` complexity.
>
> To give a hint what that inputs are:
>
> - Data point count (by default 28 but can be 14-70 or anything else > 5)
> - Date (s relative day index based on the data points)
> - Preferences (limited to 3)
> - Temperature (limited to 34-38°C in 0.05 steps)
> - A marker on a day (limited to the possible values from the data points)
>
> I have multiple algorithms which have all the same interface, but some
>   concrete algorithm just uses some fields and not all. However should I
>   need to check those other cases too since the algorithm might been
>   updated and the test was forgotten for some reasons?
>
> Do you have some best practices how to check algorithm?

Comment: `Do you have some best practices` - sounds like it may be a good one for [programmers.se]

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to understand. Maybe a toy example or concrete use-case would help. Especially unclear is what relates these algorithms/why they're bunched like that and how you could test all of them with the same code.

Comment: @theB Sounds Too Broad for Programmers.

Comment: This question (i.e. on Meta) is primarily opinion based. ;)

Comment: BTW, I think you mean "[t]he naive idea" rather than "the native idea" in that second sentence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this question will fly in Stack Overflow, it is too broad, if not unclear.

To make it work on Stack Overflow you'll need to provide a start of an implementation where you then can point out that you run into problems when you extend this to your real use-case.

One other option could be Programmers.SE but I think you need to reduce the question to a design problem. In this form it's more soliciting for opinions. I'm not an active member of programmers.SE so before posting read their [help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  or re-ask this question on their meta.